# Must all citizenships be disclosed on a Global Entry application?

Tags: dual-nationality, global-entry

I’m a dual citizen looking to apply for Global Entry. One of my citizenships is my primary one and the secondary I barely ever use (usually only to get into that country). I last renewed my passport for my secondary citizenship in 2008 and it expired in 2013 and I don’t know where my citizenship certificate is.

The GE application requires a supporting document for my secondary citizenship, and when I enter the passport info it requires that it isn’t expired. So it’s impossible for me to both disclose my dual citizenship and complete the supporting document info without providing a false date, say 2018 expiration year.

Thoughts? Is it required to disclose all citizenships or only the ones one intends to use with GE?

Comment: It is required to disclose all citizenships, but anything that the online application is preventing you from disclosing properly can be disclosed at the interview instead.  My wife had a citizenship for which she had no document at all so she just told the guy who interviewed her about it.

Comment: Note that if one of your nationalities is Canadian, [you aren't eligible for Global Entry and, instead, must apply for NEXUS, which includes Global Entry benefits](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1035/~/global-entry-program---who-can-apply).

Comment: @JimMacKenzie What part of the linked text supports that statement?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk I suppose I've misinterpreted it.  Canadian citizens clearly must apply for NEXUS.  US/Canadian dual could arguably apply for GE  So it would be situationally dependent.  NEXUS is cheaper and has more benefits, though, so is worth considering even if it's optional.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, If you are Canadian then NEXUS is an option. If you are a US LPR or have a citizenship that qualifies for GE then GE is an option. If you are American or Mexican you have both options. If you have more than one option you get to pick.

Comment: Is your second nationality ineligible for Global Entry, or worse, is it one of the "travel ban" nations? You may wish to attempt to contact them directly rather than appear to be attempting to hide something.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are required to disclose and upload the passports for all citizenships that you hold. If you are not able to do this on your online application in GOES, you can do that during your interviews and must be done. In my NEXUS interview (NEXUS is similar to GE but administered by CA and US), I was specifically asked whether I am only the citizen of the country that I uploaded passport for.